# How is this for an April 1st joke?

Tags: discussion, voting, april-fools

I know it's a little too late, but still:

In the [last post in the SO blog](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/04/new-10k-feature-inline-tagging/), Jeff said about Inline Tagging (at 10K reputation)

> well, there were also complaints that the 10k users didn’t get enough “stuff” — so this is more “stuff”..

So:

> Due to continued complain that the 10k users didn't get enough "stuff", we are introducing a new feature called "multiple votes". For every 10k of rep you have, you will get on extra vote per post. If you see a post that's particularly good, you can vote it up twice (or three times if you have 20k, ...). We trust users with 10k very much, so we know they will not abuse this power and only use it for good.

Comment: you know it's not friday anymore, right?  by servertime at least.  maybe if you're in hawaii...

Comment: "We trust users with 10k very much, so we know they will not abuse this power"---How did they get 10K, 20K in the first place, hmmm? :)

Comment: I think meta stackoverflow is lacking humour as it has a vast scope of humour

Answer (score 2):

Stackoverflow API has been released on April 1st 2010....

Answer (score 1):

**How about this for a joke:**

```
javascript:R=0; x1=.1; y1=.05; x2=.25; y2=.24; x3=1.6; y3=.24; x4=300; y4=200; x5=300; y5=200; var DI= document.getElementsByTagName("img"); DIL=DI.length; function A(){for(i=0; i<DIL; i++){DIS=DI[ i ].style; DIS.position='absolute'; DIS.left=Math.sin(R*x1+i*x2+x3)*x4+x5+"px"; DIS.top=Math.cos(R*y1+i*y2+y3)*y4+y5+"px"}R++}tag=setInterval('A()',5 );document.onmousedown=function(){clearInterval(tag);for(i=0; i<DIL; i++){DI[i].style.position="static";}}; void(0)
```

- Go to your stackoverflow homepage and put this script on the browser's address bar and see the list of people who have down-voted you

Comment: Whoa bump on an old post :P

Comment: if you try it more than once than you can see something good.